# Correct naming of beans

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, javabeans

I know about the Naming Conventions for Enterprise Beans, but I want to know about the properly way to naming different beans. In our team project we have a package `view` with beans scoped as `@ConversationScoped`, which we agreed to name as, for example, `ClientView`, `ContractView` etc., but it became necessary to add beans with `@RequestScoped` and I think it's bad idea to name these beans with `View` at the end of file name. What names should we give to our beans?

Comment: This is typically a question without fixed answers: it always depends. The golden rule is "be consistent in your naming convention". If all your backing beans, regardless the scope, are named like `XXXBacking`, it could be as long as this naming convention is consistent and does not conflict with other naming. As for your question, I think specifying a name depending on the scope is too strict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think, there is a difference between `@ConversationScoped` and `@RequestScoped` from the UI perspective. Sure there are technical differences of the two annotations, but in both cases the underlying class is still a backing bean for a view, isn't it?